# Hidden text field to be set to other Text Field value

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following form in rails:

```
<%= form_for :key, :url => delete_keys_path,:html => { :method => :get } do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :key_value %>
  <%= f.text_field :key_value %>
  <%= button_to 'Delete', :class => 'btn',
            method: :delete,
            data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for :key ,:url => unblock_keys_path,:html => { :method => :get } do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field  :key_value %>
  <%= button_to 'Unblock', :class => 'btn',
            method: :get %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for :key, url: keep_alive_keys_path, :html => { :method => :get }  do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :key_value %>
  <%= button_to 'Keep Alive', :class => 'btn',
            method: :get %>
<% end %>
```

I want the user to input a key value and choose specific action based on which button he clicks. Since only one input is needed I set up one `text field` and other hidden fields

The `hidden field` must be set equal to value in `text field` on submit. I know i will have to use JavaScript but how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign an id to the text field, say "textField", and to the hidden field as well, say "hiddenField".

Now using javascript,

```
var textFieldElement = document.getElementById("textField");
var hiddenFieldElement = document.getElementById("hiddenField");
var text = textFieldElement.value;
hiddenFieldElement.value = text;
```

Comment: How do I ensure that the javascript in `application.js` is used and not the defaut behaviour of the buttons?

Comment: event.preventDefault(); should work for you.
Refer to this link for more information and examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault